# How do I pretty-print a (semiquoted) backslash symbol as a single backslash in Racket?

Tags: escaping, racket, symbols

I'm trying to generate Haskell programs with [Xsmith](https://docs.racket-lang.org/xsmith/). The generated AST is rendered into a program by walking the tree and generating semiquoted expressions. Finally, theses expressions are pretty-printed to open-output-string. It seems to work quicker than using `format` at every node, but doesn't properly render the single backslashes I need for haskell lambda functions:
[Generating an example lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUJpY.png)
Is there any way to generate the expression I need?

Here is the provided code for the renderer

```
 (define (boolhaskell-format-render s-exps)
  (define out (open-output-string))
  (for ([symex s-exps])
    (pretty-print symex out 1))
  (get-output-string out))
```

Comment: Need example expressions and what the result should look like, but I'm guessing no because Haskell expressions aren't s-expressions.

Comment: Pretty-printing produces valid source code, and a lone backslash is not valid Racket. You might be able to configure the pretty printer, otherwise you need to write your own.